# what patterns are recommended as a js module equivalent in ng2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What patterns are recommended as a js modules in ng2?  For example, let's say my ng2.component.ts grows into 50 functions and it would be appropriate to encapsulate 40 of these functions into its own js module so normally I would create a js module like this:

```
var ModuleX = (function () {

   //group the 40 cohesive functions in this module

})();
```

I'm assuming that ng2 uses some type of proprietary structure as opposed to generic js modules.  In ng2 would I create a ModuleX.component.ts and then call this component from another component and avoid the use of generic js modules entirely?

Answer (score 0):

If these 50 functions are actually helper functions and would help you across multiple components, their best location/implementation is inside of a dedicated [service(s)](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

Comment: I'll give you a more specific problem statement. I have a few methods with jQuery hooks in my ng2 component which are required to support a legacy 3rd party jQuery component. I would prefer to delegate this logic to an independent module so for example I'd like to include a method in MyComponentX like this:

configureJQuery()
{
   XJQueryManager.ConfigureJQuery(controls);     
}

This approach would separate the jQuery and isolate it in it's own module or component or whatever the best structure is for this in ng2

Comment: I think ng2 services are designed to be used mainly as passthrough service wrappers